# Using Math.Pow with Microsoft Solver Foundation

Tags: c#, math, solver, ms-solver-foundation

I'm working on a simple solver exercise and I'm struggling to use `Math.Pow`.

Why I can't use `Math.Pow(error1, 2)` in the following lines?

```
error1 = error1 * error1;
error2 = error2 * error2;
```

It gives an error:

> Error 3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Term' to 'double'

The relevant code:

```
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Common;
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services;

... 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    var solver = SolverContext.GetContext();
    var model = solver.CreateModel();
    Decision R = new Decision(Domain.Real, "R");
    Decision T = new Decision(Domain.Real, "T");
    model.AddDecisions(R);
    model.AddDecisions(T);

    var xr1=5;
    var xr2=4;
    var xp1 = 6;
    var xp2=8;
    var error1 = xr1 * R + T - xp1;
    var error2 = xr2 * R + T - xp2;
    error1 = error1 * error1;
    error2 = error2 * error2;
    model.AddGoal("error",GoalKind.Minimize,error1+error2);

    var solution = solver.Solve();
    var valordeR = R.GetDouble();
    var valordeT = T.GetDouble();
}
```

Comment: Because [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) method doesn't have an overload takes [`Decision`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.decision(v=vs.93).aspx) as a parameter?

Comment: I just edited my post, the error is: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Term' to 'double'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Model.Power`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.model.power%28v=vs.93%29.aspx) method. [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) is for doubles only.

```
error1 = Model.Power(error1, 2);
error2 = Model.Power(error2, 2);
```